# Xcode 14 Key Bindings: Default Conflicts and Non-Functional Bindings

Tags: xcode, macos, key-bindings

Without any customization whatsoever, there are 25 key binding conflicts in Xcode 14. This is the default set that Apple created. What’s more, many of the existing key bindings do not work.

One important binding that I use with muscle memory is “insert new line and leave section before it.” Xcode uses control+O for the default binding, but it doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of the Xcode key bindings panel in settings]

I can’t add a custom binding for the aforementioned command, or any other for that matter. When I try to add custom bindings Xcode notes a conflict. But its original binding doesn’t function.

Every other editor uses this and other bindings by default, so I can’t understand why Xcode won’t allow them, even as a customization.

Does anyone know how to resolve these conflicts, fix the bindings, and/or force Xcode to respect custom bindings?

Thanks in advance.